# Sequel example won't run

Tags: ruby, yaml, sequel

I've just installed "sequel" gem for Ruby. I wanted to try example from Sequel website and it won't work :(
test.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite # memory database

DB.create_table :items do
    primary_key :id
    String :name
    Float :price
end

items = DB[:items] # Create a dataset

# Populate the table
items.insert(:name => 'abc', :price => rand * 100)
items.insert(:name => 'def', :price => rand * 100)
items.insert(:name => 'ghi', :price => rand * 100)

# Print out the number of records
puts "Item count: #{items.count}"

# Print out the average price
puts "The average price is: #{items.avg(:price)}"
```

Console:

```
$ sequel test.rb
Error: ArgumentError: syntax error on line 11, col 37: `i'/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run this with `ruby` not `sequel`

```
$ ruby test.rb
```

Comment: +1 because this should work, if not, there is something wrong with your ruby or sequel installation. What are the errors for `ruby test.rb`?

Comment: /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': LoadError: no such file to load -- sqlite3 (Sequel::AdapterNotFound)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.13.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:1
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `k_require'
(and more...)

I have installed sequel by "gem install sequel". Ramaze works fine.

Comment: You need to install sqlite3 as well.

Comment: Technically, you need the sqlite3-ruby gem: "sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby"